# Sharepoint from to add row to list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-list

I want to create a form that can add data (each form info = one row) to a sharepoint list that I have created.
The list has 5 columns and the form will have 5 fields. Submitting a form adds data to the list, just like a new item form.

The only difference is that I need a link to the form that can be sent to anyone via email, who can just fill it without being able to remove anything else from that list themselves.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this with permissions.  You can create a new permission level and give it Add Items access but not Edit or Delete.  Create a group that has this permission and add users to it.

Comment: The permissions are not an issue, but the actual binding is. I can't figure out how to click the submit the form button on an InfoPath form which populates the sharepoint list

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Lists web service and the CAML Batch method to submit data to that data to the list.

[Submitting to a SharePoint List](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/infopath/2007/03/26/submitting-to-a-sharepoint-list/)

[5 Ways to submit an InfoPath form to a SharePoint list](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2008/5-ways-to-submit-an-infopath-form-to-a-sharepoint-list.htm)

But, if the user who has Delete permission visits to the list in browser, he still can delete the list item.